# Обновление содержимого div без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте! Помогите реализовать функцию.

Есть DIV, который должен обновляться по нажатию на ссылку, при этом не перезагружая всю страницу целиком.

P.S Дополню. Нужно менять содержимое DIV блока, в зависимости от того, по какой сслыке перешел пользователь.

Т.Е

```
<a href="index.html#content" class="game"></a>
```

При переходе по этой ссылке, содержимое DIV блока должно меняться на тот контент, который присутствует в DIV с другим ID .  Содержимое другого DIV скрывать с параметром

```
display none;
```

Это мои личные соображения. Если что либо непонятно, я дополню.

Comment: Напишите подробнее, что именно должно происходить с блоком и откуда грузятся данные

Comment: @unnamed, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Поддерживаю @osrsoft, как правило, для таких целей используют технологии [ajax](http://javascript.ru/ajax/intro), задача которых асинхронно обновлять данные отдельных блоков. В [данном](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=1452) примере будет необходимо подключить библиотеку jquery.

Answer (score -4):

```
<a href="index.html#content" class="game" onclick=d-none('.div-class')></a>
```

JS

```
    function d-none(in) {
       var div = document.querySelector(in);
       //querySelector можно заменить на getElementByClassName или getElementById
       div.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Там пишут разные комментаторы разное и доколупываются до мелочей. Но главное пеализация а уж вы сами допиливайте как вам надо
А вообще для этой задачки лучше использовать angular c ng-style и ng-click
Либо jQuery c .css();

Comment: Вы выбираете все элементы, а затем скрываете только первый.
Почему тогда не использовать просто `document.querySelector();`?

Comment: добавлю что: 1. function d-none выдаст syntax error, потому что d-none содержит дефис и прям вот так вот функцию с дефисом в имени создать нельзя 2. class - ключевое слово в современном js, называть параметр функции class - нельзя 3. Вы легким движением руки создаете глобальную переменную с именем div. 4. Ну и html соответственно тоже невалидный. И все это в таком простом кусочке кода. Резюме: ответ ужасен, рекомендую удалить